# What determines if a downloaded file should be saved as read-only or read-write?

Tags: http, permissions, http-headers, download, readonly

When you write some binary data in the http response stream (of Servlet etc) or using the Content-disposition header, what is the factor that determines whether the downloaded file is saved as readonly or has write permissions ? How can we control whether to make it read-only or not? Is that browser/OS dependant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only [specified parameters for the *Content-Disposition* header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183) are `filename`, `creation-date`, `modification-date`, `read-date`, and `size`. You may use custom parameters (see [ABNF of *parameter* syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.1)), but they are will probably not be supported by user agents unless they are registered with the IANA.

So, no, it is currently not possible to set access properties like *read only*.