# Creating read only file when download

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipart

My requirement is to upload a file in read only format using spring mvc and download same file in read only.
I am able to upload file in read only format but after download it lost read only property.

Code for file upload :-

```
File destinationFile = new File ( targetPath);

try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( destinationFile );

    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    stream = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
    stream.write(bytes);

    destinationFile.setReadOnly();
    destinationFile.setWritable(false);

}finally {
    if(stream != null){
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Code for download :-

```
File file = new File(folderPath);
contentType = "application/octet-stream";

response.setBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disposition + ";filename=\"" + filename  + "\"");

RandomAccessFile input = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
long start, long length;

byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int read;

if (input.length() == length) {
    while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
} else {
    input.seek(start);
    long toRead = length;

    while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        if ((toRead -= read) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
        } else {
            output.write(buffer, 0, (int) toRead + read);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you mean that once someone downloads the file they can edit it?

Comment: No it should be in read only format. It can't be edited.

Comment: You should close the file before setting it to read-only. Your download code in the second case does not look right. You should never write more than you just read. I don't see why you need two copy loops here, or a `RandomAccessFile`: just use a `FileInputStream` and `skip(start)` it if `start > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set yourself the read only attribute with:

```
file.setReadOnly();
```

From the [documentation of the setReadOnly method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadOnly--):

> **public boolean setReadOnly()**
>
> Marks the file or directory named by this abstract pathname so that only read operations are allowed. After invoking this method the file or directory will not change until it is either deleted or marked to allow write access. On some platforms it may be possible to start the Java virtual machine with special privileges that allow it to modify files that are marked read-only. Whether or not a read-only file or directory may be deleted depends upon the underlying system.

Comment: At which time we have to set this ? After downloading the file ?

Comment: Yes, after creation of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is impossible.

Once the file is on a user's machine that you do not control you cannot enforce anything about the file.

You can sign it with a key to detect tampering, they will still be able to edit it, but you will know they have done it.

You cannot even set a read-only flag, as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785666/what-determines-if-a-downloaded-file-should-be-saved-as-read-only-or-read-write) confirms, as there is no read only header, and even if you made a downloader which respected this header, and set the flag on the file the user could just remove the read only flag from the file and be able to edit it.